# Tomcat behind nginx proxy provides new jsessionids for each request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat, proxypass

I have a ReactJS based web app being served by nginx on /. This web app contacts a web service running on Tomcat which is running on port 8443 on the same machine. I have set up a proxy_pass on nginx to pass any request received on /APIServer to the Tomcat server.

The proxy pass sends the requests on /APIServer successfully to the Tomcat server. But the problem is that Tomcat provides a new `JSESSIONID` value for each request from the web app. Every response from Tomcat has a `Set-Cookie` header with a new `JSESSIONID` while there is no `Cookie` header sent from the client for each request after the first.

My nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/analytics-ui;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /APIServer/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/;
    }
}
```

I have added the proxy headers after researching how to resolve this issue, but so far none of the solutions have worked. Tomcat still provides new `JSESSIONID`s for each request from the web app. This causes issues in the web app for functionality such as login and authorization.

The API on the Tomcat server works if I call it directly using Postman or a web browser.

Is there something I am overlooking or is there any additional configuration required to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am a klutz.

The reason this wasn't working was because I wasn't using SSL on nginx while Tomcat was using SSL. I set up SSL in nginx and now it works as expected.